# sudo apt-get install ssh

Tags: ssh, apt, osx, password

On my Mac terminal when I put sudo apt-get install ssh, its answer password. I dont have it. How can I find it please

[image]

Comment: apt is for deb-based Linux distros (Debian, Ubuntu and their direvatives). On Mac OS X use homebrew. ``sudo`` asked your for password. read ``man sudo``

Answer (score 4):

Putting aside for the moment the fact that you're using `apt` on a Mac, when you run `sudo` it asks for *your* password.  Which you should have if you're already logged into the computer itself.

Answer (score 3):

Please try to understand your tools and what you are doing.

Activating SSH in a Mac is done selecting "System preferences"->Sharing and ticking the box "Remote Login".

The `apt` command/package manager is for Debian-based Linux systems.